# VS2012: Program can't start because "libvorbisfile.dll" is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vorbis, oggvorbis

I've got a project and I'm trying to make it read a .OGG file.
I've downloaded the `libogg` and `libvorbis` from [here](http://xiph.org/downloads/), compiled them (had some trouble figuring I had to build libogg first), then got the following files:

```
libogg.lib
libogg.dll
libvorbis.lib
libvorbis.dll
libvorbisfile.lib
libvorbisfile.dll
```

I dragged all of them in my project's Libraries folder, already added to the project, and included them in the Linker->Input (only the .lib).

Next I copied the headers to my project's Includes folder, also already added to the project, with the files:

```
ogg/ogg.h
ogg/os_types.h

vorbis/codec.h
vorbis/vorbisenc.h
vorbis/vorbisfile.h
```

Then I added some code, and I get the error *"The program can't start because libvorbisfile.dll is missing from the computer."*
And I'm pretty sure the file IS in the Library folder and properly defined in the properties.

Did I do something wrong along the way?
How can I figure what is wrong so I can fix it?

I already tried putting the .dll in the project's folder and in the Windows/System32 folder as well, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library folder is fine for your .lib files, but it's looking for the .dll at run time, which your project settings have no effect on. Windows looks in a few places for a .dll, but the easiest way to get your program to run is to put the .dlls in your working directory, which is where ever you run your executable from (probably the same directory as the .exe file).

Comment: Already tried that as well, didn't work. Usually putting them in the Windows/Sys32 - 64 folder always solve this, but not this time... so I'm guessing something VERY wrong is going on...

Comment: I re-read your answer and noticed you suggested to put in the Debug/Release folder, not in the project's... I tried that and it worked! Although I'm not sure why ONLY these (all three had to be moved there, ogg, vorbis and vorbisfile) must be there...

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx

You may have put the .dll in the wrong `system` folder. Use the function mentioned in the article to see if you put the .dlls in the right place.